# Moving a value along a 2d grid

Tags: c++, arrays, grid, char

I am trying to write an application, in which the user inputs an integer

- 1 = up,
- 2 = down
- 3 = left
- 4 = right and
- x : moves along the 3x3 grid.

I am not sure what I have done wrong, so any help would be appreciated.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char player = 'x';
char grid[3][3] = {{ player, '.' ,'.'},{'.', '.', '.' },{'.', '.', '.' } };

void Draw() {
    for (int row = 0; row <= 2; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col <= 2; col++) {
        cout << grid[row][col];
    }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
int posX = 0;
int posY = 0;
int in;
Draw();
while (1) {
    cin >> in;
    if (in == 1) {
        grid[posY][posX] = '.';
        posY = posY - 1;
        grid[posY][posX] = player;
    }
    else if (in == 2) {
        grid[posY][posX] = '.';
        posY = posY + 1;
        grid[posY][posX] = player;
    }
    else if (in == 3) {
        grid[posY][posX] = '.';
        posX = posX - 1;
        grid[posY][posX] = player;
    }
    else if (in == 4) {
        grid[posY][posX] = '.';
        posX = posX + 1;
        grid[posY][posX] = player;
    }
    else {
        grid[posY][posX] = player;
    }
    system("cls");
    Draw();
}
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your grid looks like 2×3, not 3×3 to me.

Comment: It is not immediately clear to me what the *intended* output or behaviour is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have compile it and everything is ok.... But you must check if the player is on the max side of grid, and then if player want to move you must stop him, because of wall of course;>
Example :

```
    while (1)
{
    cin >> in;
    if (in == 1)
    {
        if(posY>0) // HERE
        {
            grid[posY][posX] = '.';
            posY = posY - 1;
            grid[posY][posX] = player;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @KhatanbuuveiBold no problemo;)